# Why was AbstractList designed so that some methods always throw UnsupportedException?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn AbstractList I found some method always throws an exception, my question is why design like this?

```
 /**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 *
 * <p>This implementation always throws an
 * {@code UnsupportedOperationException}.
 *
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws ClassCastException            {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws NullPointerException          {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException      {@inheritDoc}
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException     {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E set(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Comment: This is a common approach. The idea is you subclass `AbstractList` and override those methods with real implementations.

Comment: @MattGreer: Then why can't these method be left unimplemented. Its abstract class!!

Comment: Well, I think reason could be they don't want to enforce. if they leave it as abstract, then it is mandatory that subclass need to provide implementation. In this case, it is not mandatory. It is upto implementer to decide. Most of the times why can be answered by only group of language designers who worked on it.

Answer (score 4):

The Java language designers used this approach instead of adding mutable and immutable list subtypes to avoid an explosion in the Collections type hierarchy.   See the [Java Collections API Design FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#1).